# Tesseract : Index out of bounds exceptions for OCR method

Tags: java, tesseract, tess4j

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I am using Tesseract for OCR. I am getting an Index out of bounds exception for the file I am passing. Any ideas?

Error log :

```
et.sourceforge.tess4j.TesseractException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:215)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:196)
    at com.tooltank.spring.service.GroupAttachmentsServiceImpl.testOcr(GroupAttachmentsServiceImpl.java:839)
    at com.tooltank.spring.service.GroupAttachmentsServiceImpl.lambda$addAttachment$0(GroupAttachmentsServiceImpl.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at javax.imageio.stream.FileCacheImageOutputStream.seek(FileCacheImageOutputStream.java:170)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.ImageIOHelper.getImageByteBuffer(ImageIOHelper.java:297)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.setImage(Tesseract.java:397)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:290)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:212)
    ... 4 more
```

Code :

```
 private String testOcr(String fileLocation, int attachId) {
        try {
            File imageFile = new File(fileLocation);
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
            BufferedImage blackNWhite = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
            Graphics2D graphics = blackNWhite.createGraphics();
            graphics.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
            String identifier = String.valueOf(new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32));
            String blackAndWhiteImage = previewPath + identifier + ".png";
            File outputfile = new File(blackAndWhiteImage);
            ImageIO.write(blackNWhite, "png", outputfile);

            ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
            // Point to one folder above tessdata directory, must contain training data
            instance.setDatapath("/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/");
            // ISO 693-3 standard
            instance.setLanguage("deu");
            String result = instance.doOCR(outputfile);
            result = result.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9öÖäÄüÜß@\\s]", "");
            Files.delete(new File(blackAndWhiteImage).toPath());
            GroupAttachments groupAttachments = this.groupAttachmentsDAO.getAttachmenById(attachId);
            System.out.println("OCR Result is "+result);
            if (groupAttachments != null) {
                saveIndexes(result, groupAttachments.getFileName(), null, groupAttachments.getGroupId(), false, attachId);
            }
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Due to a bug in Java Image IO (which was fixed with Java 9), the current version of Java Tesseract Wrapper (3.4.0 as this answer was written) does not work with < Java 9. To work with lower Java versions, you can try the following fix to Tesseract ImageIOHelper class. Simply make a copy of the class in your project and apply the necessary changes and it will work with both files and BufferedImages smoothly.

Note: This version does not use the Tiff optimization used in the original class, you can add it if it is necessary for your project.

```
public static ByteBuffer getImageByteBuffer(RenderedImage image) throws IOException {
    //Set up the writeParam
    if (image instanceof BufferedImage) {
        return convertImageData((BufferedImage) image);
    }
    ColorModel cm = image.getColorModel();
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    WritableRaster raster = cm
            .createCompatibleWritableRaster(width, height);
    boolean isAlphaPremultiplied = cm.isAlphaPremultiplied();
    Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
    String[] keys = image.getPropertyNames();
    if (keys != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            properties.put(keys[i], image.getProperty(keys[i]));
        }
    }
    BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(cm, raster,
            isAlphaPremultiplied, properties);
    image.copyData(raster);
    return convertImageData(result);
}
```

Comment: So I should replace the getImageBytBuffer method in ImageIOHelper with the code you provided. How do I call the OCR method? Thanks.

Comment: Just add the fixed copy to the classpath and call tesseract the usual way, it will use your fixed copy before the library copy.

Comment: Sorry, didn't work, same exception. I put that file in a different package and added that package in Module Settings->Modules->Dependencies in Intellij 13.

Comment: You are still using the old code then, confirm it with debugging and check your dependencies, your package with the fixed code should have precedence over tesseract package.

Comment: Finally added that in libraries instead of dependencies, looks like it's working. Will add it on our server and confirm within a day. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to tess4j version 3.4.1. 
That solved the issue for me.